# Can I repair a luggage caster housing with Sugru?

Tags: repair, plastic

Something got stuck around the fixed axle of my suitcase caster,  causing the caster to stop rotating around it. The axle itself ended up rotating and wearing away at the housing.

I managed to clear the majority of the blockage, but because the housing is worn away, the caster now rubs against the top side of the housing.

Can I use [Sugru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugru) to pad the worn out section of the housing? It's the only thing I have even vaguely suited to the job. How else could I repair it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely that suguru will be durable enough for your requirements. It's a flexible material, but not a high-wear sort of product.

On the other hand, if the hand-moldable aspect of suguru fits your needs, you may find that [hand-moldable plastic](http://www.michaels.com/friendly-plastic-pellets/10436169.html) will work better. It's poly-type plastic, relatively slippery but quite strong when cool.

I've used the stuff for various projects in the past. The instructions suggest to put a baggie of pellets in hot water and when they change from opaque to clear, form in place to create the desired object. I'm impatient and discovered that one can build a tiny tin foil tray and use a hot air gun. This method saves time and creates incredibly hot plastic which burns skin. It's the timing that matters, as one can begin to use the plastic once it is completely clear and not burn one's skin as easily.

[image: bag o' pellets]

The above link points to Michaels' stores, while a similar product can be found on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003QKLJKQ) as well as many other locations on the 'net.

[image: more pellets]

Comment: Another name is polymorph or, more generically [Polycaprolactone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycaprolactone), a cup of boiled water works well to soften it to hand-holdable temperature. As strong as nylon when set.

Answer (score 0):

No. That material sounds much too soft if it's anything like silicone, and will likely tear in short order. You need an epoxy that's designed to bond to plastic.